# Getting FOUC in Next.js with basic scss stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, next.js

I'm importing my stylesheet in a custom `/pages/_app.js` file, however, I get a FOUC on page refresh. I've tried explicitly calling the file inside `<Head>` tag but that didn't work either. Also, might be worth mentioning that I'm using a component-level CSS approach for my individual components (`Component.module.scss`) - unsure if this affects anything.

I'm new to Next.js so I'm not sure if I'm missing anything obvious. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm out of ideas. Thanks!

**The `_app.js` file:**

```
import Head from "next/head"

import "../styles/styles.scss"
import { FirebaseContextProvider } from "../context/FirebaseContext"
import DefaultLayout from "../layouts/Default"

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const defaultTitle = "Site Name"
  const defaultDescription = "Description goes here."

  const Layout = Component["layout"] || DefaultLayout
  const Title = Component["title"] || defaultTitle
  const Description = Component["description"] || defaultDescription

  return (
    <FirebaseContextProvider>
      <Layout>
        <Head>
          <title>{Title}</title>
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
          <meta name="description" content={Description}></meta>
        </Head>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </FirebaseContextProvider>
  )
}
```

**Part of the `styles.scss` file:**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;600;700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
@import "./_variables.scss";

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font: 14px $font-stack;
  font-weight: 300;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```